# React.js: why search filter doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make work **search input**. I'm filtering through fetched data in **useEffect** in **Hooks/useCountries** component, listening to **input** in **App.js** and passing props for **handleChange**  in **Searchbar** component. Something is missing, I can't figure out what. 
 Here is the link of [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/qu0hv?file=/src/App.js) and **Hooks/useCountries** component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function useCountries(search) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const fetchData = () => {
    fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => setData(result))
      .catch((err) => console.log("error"));
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const searchResult =
      data &&
      data
        .filter((item) => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(search))
        .map((element) => <div>{element.name}</div>);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return [data, error];
}
```

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import SearchBar from "./components/SearchBar";
import useCountries from "./Hooks/useCountries";
import MainTable from "./components/MainTable";

import "./App.scss";

export default function App() {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [data, error] = useCountries(search);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SearchBar handleChange={handleChange} search={search} />
      <MainTable countries={data} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

SearchBar component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import "./SearchBar.scss";

export default function Searchbar({ handleChange, search }) {
  return (
    <div className="SearchBar">
      <input
        className="input"
        type="text"
        placeholder="search country ..."
        value={search}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: "Something is missing" is very vague statement of problem. What do you expect and what are you getting instead?

Comment: Hey @Jay Codist  now I'm only listening to input. If I type anything, I can see in console.
I want to get data which matches my search

Answer (score 0):

So in your `useCountries` hook, you need to update the useEffect to trigger whenever search is changed. Otherwise, it runs when the hook is first loaded, but then never again. I'm also not exactly sure what your logic is attempting to accomplish in your current `useEffect`. I've posted a possible update to it that also changes your search to regex to account for the possibility that the user may not be typing in lower case. Let me know if this doesn't work for your use case and I can adapt it.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function useCountries(search) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState(null);
  const fetchData = () => {
    fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => setData(result))
      .catch((err) => console.log("error"));
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (search) {
      const searchCriteria = new RegExp(search, "i");
      setSearchResults(
        data
          .filter((item) => searchCriteria.test(item.name))
          .map((element) => <div>{element.name}</div>)
      );
    } else {
      setSearchResults(null);
    }
  }, [search]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return [data, error, searchResults];
}
```

And in App.js add:

```js
const [data, error, searchResults] = useCountries(search);
```

Here is the fork off of your sandbox where this works:
[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-volhard-f56up)

Comment: Hey @technicallynick thank you for answer.  Do I have to import "usememo" or install, it says 'useMemo' is not defined

Comment: ok, I imported it. Where should I use "searchResults"?

Comment: Hey @technicallynick whatever  I type in console I see "empty arrays []"

Comment: So you should update your App.js to include the new searchResults returned from `useCountries`. So it should look like: `const [data, error, searchResults] = useCountries(search);`. If you're still not getting results, then I would suggest spinning up an environment in CodeSandbox so I can see what's happening.

Comment: Hey @technicallynick it still doesn't work. Console output is "null". 
And here is codesandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/qu0hv?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Greg - I updated my answer with a fork of your sandbox with a working example.

Comment: Hey @technicallynick thank you for getting back to me and help. 
But the changes you've done, are available only  to you. Codesandbox changes the link address in terms of safety. In my link it's the same, that I'd sent to you.
 You have to send the link to me, please.

Comment: I've fixed the link. It should now load to my fork. Not sure why it didn't before.